# How do I compress a SQL query string to a small string less than 258 chars?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to create a unique small string <= 258 chars that is suitable as a windows filename.

This is to uniquely label a Xml query result.

Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT [utcDT],
MAX(CASE WHEN[Symbol] = 'fish' THEN[Close] END) AS [fish],
MAX(CASE WHEN[Symbol] = 'chips' THEN[Close] END) AS [chips]
FROM [DATA].[1M].[ASTS_NOGAP]
WHERE [Date] >= '2011-12-27'
AND [Date] <= '2012-07-01'
AND [Symbol] IN ('fish','chips')
GROUP BY [utcDT] ) AS A 
WHERE [utcDT] IS NOT NULL  AND [fish] IS NOT NULL AND [chips] IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY [utcDT]
```

BUT is could be a longer query.

The compress is one way only, i.e. I do NOT need to decompress.

I want to end up with a unique file name like:

```
 ksdgfsbhdfjksgdjbajysjdgyasagfdjahgdkjasgjgfjkgjkgdjkfgjskdjfgsajgdjfgjsgy.xml
```

> EDIT1:
>
> The generated filename must be unique to the query - such that another
>   app would generate the same filename for the same query.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you create a hash and base 64 encode?

Comment: Use a GUID as the name

Comment: Do you need the string to be generated from the query code? Maybe a simple `Guid` does the trick.

Comment: I'm in the GUID camp   Select concat('FileName-',newid(),'.xml')

Comment: Can't use GUID. The filename must be unique to the query i.e. another process would generate the same filename from the same query

Comment: If the SQL string is longer than 258 characters, there is no way to guarantee that you won't get a collision. I.e., you cannot guarantee that the generated string is unique.

Comment: So if the query you posted above had a different set of date "arguments" (or even just 1 different), would the file name be the same or different from the one for your posted query? How about if the order by clause was the only difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small risk for collisions, but this should do what you need:

```
public string GetUniqueFileNameForQuery(string sql)
{
    using (var hasher = SHA256.Create())
    {
        var queryBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sql);
        var queryHash = hasher.ComputeHash(queryBytes);
                         // "/" may be included, but is not legal for file names
        return Convert.ToBase64String(queryHash).Replace("/", "-")+".xml";
    }
}
```

This needs `using System.Security.Cryptography;` at the top of the file.

---

I also need to add a note about working with SQL from client code languages like C#.

Most queries are going to need input of some kind: an ID field for a lookup, a date range, a username, *something* to tell the query which records you need out of a larger set. It's **very poor practice** to substitute these inputs directly into the SQL string in your C# (or other language) code. That opens you up to an issue known as SQL Injection, and *it's kind of a big deal*.

Instead, for most all queries, there will be a placeholder variable name for each input argument. It matters for this question because you'll have the *same SQL query text* for two queries that differ only by arguments.

For example, say you have this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username
```

You run this query twice, once with `'jsmith'` as the input, and once with `'jdoe'`. *The SQL didn't change,* and therefore the encoded file name didn't change.

You maybe be inclined to ask to get the value of the SQL *after* the parameter inputs are substituted into the query, but this misunderstands what happens. The parameter inputs are *never, at any time, substituted into the sql query*. That's the whole point. Even the database server will instead treat them as procedure variables.

The point here is you also need a way to encode any parameter data used with your query. Here's one basic naive option:

```
public string GetUniqueFileNameForQuery(DbCommand query)
{
    var sql = query.CommandText;
    foreach(var p in query.Parameters)
    {
        sql = sql.Replace(p.Name, p.Value.ToString());
    }

    using (var hasher = SHA256.Create())
    {
        var queryBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sql);
        var queryHash = hasher.ComputeHash(queryBytes);
                         // "/" may be included, but is not legal for file names
        return Convert.ToBase64String(queryHash).Replace("/", "-")+".xml";
    }
}
```

Note: this code could produce invalid SQL. For example, you might end up with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE LastName = O'Brien
```

But since you're not actually trying to run the query, that should be okay. You also need to be careful with systems like OleDB, which uses positional matching and `?` for all parameter placeholders. In this case, the parameter name won't match the placeholder, or even if it did, the first parameter would match the placeholder for all the others.

Comment: Appreciate the full response. So it will create the SAME unique filename each time it is called IF Sql query is the same?

Comment: Yes, it will create the same hash for the same input.

Comment: Note that base64 strings are case-sensitive, but Windows file names are not.  So that increases (small) the risk of a hash collision.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Ooh, good point! We could do some fun things to work around that (maybe use a character legal for file names but not used by base64 to indicate the following character is uppercase), but I'll leave that for the OP.

Comment: Hmm... casting each byte as unsigned short, calling ToString(), and leftpadding with 0s to give the same length would work, too.